# My firebase cloud function to fetch URLs results in robot detections

Tags: firebase, httprequest, fetch-api, node-fetch

i'm trying to make a simple GET request to external URLs from my cloud function using node-fetch. When a user pastes a link, I'm making this request to retrieve social media sharing tags to populate title, description and image. Some websites seem to be responding with robot messages. Is there a way around this?

So far I've made sure the origin of the request is coming from my domain and not some strange cloud server. I've also tried defining a browser based user agent in the header without much luck.

Any ideas on other things I can check for?

Comment: You _are_ a robot. Could you respect the website's wishes instead?

Comment: It's no different than what Facebook or Twitter does when you past a link. Not sure what you mean, not a robot.

Comment: A server making a request on your behalf is generally considered a robot in this case.

Comment: The request is triggered by a user, it's the only time the request happens. That is not a robot. If you're not going to be helpful than optimize your time somewhere else

Comment: Definitions aside, this is a server that makes requests on a users' behalf. For lots of reasons people don't like that, and they probably express this in (sorry, it's true.. `robots.txt`). You are fighting a war of attrition because no matter how sophisticated you get with avoiding detection, people will continue to try to get more sophisticated in detecting you.

Comment: So if you can re-think this issue and avoid it, it might be a better path because there is no single answer that's a universal solution to this.